# Best way in terms of performance to get data for categories on site? (hard-coded, ajax, etc)

Tags: ajax, database, search, model-view-controller, categories

The situation is:

- The site has a header with a search functionality
- Search options are: category, subcategory, subsubcategory, city and a search input field
- The header of the site stays the same the whole time (it looks the same in every page of the site)

**The database has:**

- 60 rows of cities in a city table
- 6 categories in cat table
- 30 subcategories in subcat table
- 90 subsubcategories in subsubcat table

**My question is:**

What's the best way to display them?

---

**Through AJAX?:**
 (Max 4 requests)

- Get categories on button press
- When category is selected, the subcategories appear
- When subcategory is selected, the subsubcategories appear
- Get cities on button press

**Hard-Coded:**

- Every category, subcategory, subsubcategory, city is hard-coded in JavaScript's array

**Through MVC:**

- Just send category, subcategory, subsubcategory data from Model to Controller and from Controller to the Header View.

---

The more specific thing is, **I'm** really **interested in** how it's gonna impact the **performance** of the site. Let's say there are 10 visitors on the site and they are browsing the site, jumping from one page to another:

If the category data is being sent through MVC, every time a visitor goes to other page, he requests 186 (60+6+30+90) rows from 4 queries from Database, if there are 10 of them they request around 1860 rows and 40 queries.

Now with AJAX, the only time the category data is requested when the visitors specifically use the search functionality, so there would be a lot less requests.

Hard-coded is probably is the least performance intensive, I guess. But there is too much work to be done when, let's say, the Admin wants to add new categories, new cities, etc.

Maybe there is another way which I am not aware of?

Comment: I would - build the simplest working thing initially. Time it to see what is slow. Now start changing it for AJAX etc. Time It. Getting that working will be a lot easier than trying to build it initially? And you have something to show people.

Comment: I think AJAX subqueries more relevant, also if your data are not changed very frequently, you can to cache it on server side and update this cache when needed.